# How do I display dashs as minus signs outside comments and strings?

Tags: display, characters

In source code, I'd like to display “-” as “−”.  In the font I use, the dash is very short and doesn't match the “+” at all.  This is only to improve visual appearance.  The character in the file must remain the same because it is code, which need to stay correct.

So far, I've used:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                                    '(("\\B-\\B"
                                       (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)  "−"
                                                                 'decompose-region)
                                                 nil)))))
            ))
```

The `\B-\B` magic is so that this does not apply in *text*, i.e. within strings or comments, because I need it still displayed as a dash there.

Unfortunately, this cause a lot of false negatives.

Is there a way to automatically display one character as another outside strings and comments?

Comment: Yes, there are ways to perform a *replacement* such as you describe. But the question is not clear (to me), because you do *not* attempt any replacement; you are just changing the display/appearance (using font lock), not the text. Just what are you really trying to do? Do you want to replace a character or just display it differently?

Comment: I only want to replace it.  Font/colour/etc are not important.  I do it in my snippet with font-lock because this is want I found on the Internet a couple of years ago for this problem.

Comment: FWIW, maybe it is not clear with the browser font you use but: The character between `\\B-\\B` and the one later on in `"−"` is different.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood @Drew 's comment.  It seems to me you want to **display** some characters differently, but not change them **in the buffer/file**. Or do you?

Comment: Yes, it is only about appearance.  I clarified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing whether some position is inside a comment or a string is hidden behind the obscurely named function `syntax-ppss` and its return value.  I suppose the following will work.

```el
(defun python-compose-dashs (limit)
  (while (search-forward "-" limit t)
    (unless (or (nth 3 (syntax-ppss))   ;string
                (nth 4 (syntax-ppss)))  ;comment
      (compose-region
       (1- (point)) (point) "−" 'decompose-region))))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda nil
            (font-lock-add-keywords nil '((python-compose-dashs)))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately in many cases, the dash is displayed as a minus in strings, immediately after having opened the file.  If I edit the string, dashes are displayed as dashes.